# How does the output of the sigmoid function of two matrices multiplied look like?

Tags: math, sigmoid

Assuming I have the function `sigmoid(W*x)` where `W` is a 2x2 matrix and `x` is a 2x1 matrix. How would that output `sigmoid(W*x)` look like?

Comment: "q is 2x1 matrix". There is no `q` in the question. Did you mean `x`?

Comment: yes i did mean x, but i figured it out thank you

Comment: Great! In this case, you can answer your own question in case other people would be interested later.

Answer (score 0):

Sigmoid function will do an element wise operation, so each value in array will be 1/1+e^-(value)